# React Typescript: add location state to react router component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, react-router

I have a normal route

```
function LoginPage(props: RouteComponentProps): React.ReactElement {...
}
```

that uses `RouteComponentProps` from `react-router-dom`.

Strangely there were no issues for a long time with this component, but now it is failing to compile on travis-ci when I use `history.push(location.state.from.pathname)` saying `Property 'from' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I set this state in my PrivateRoute component that is pretty standard with a Redirect

```
<Redirect
  to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
/>
```

How can I update the typing for `location` to include a `from` object with `pathname: string;`

EDIT:

The solution was to add

`COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/`

to my Dockerfile after I copied the package.json over.

Comment: Caused by https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you do not use lock files for the packages. I would suggest you find a working environment (in the previously generated docker image, or from one of the team members), and generate package-lock.json (or yarn.lock) there. I used this command for it `npm install --package-lock`. It will help you for the first time until the issue will be solved completely.

Comment: Maybe I miss the point, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: @pzaenger It does answer the question of how to fix compile failing, but as I said before, it is a temporary solution.

Comment: Holy shit, you were actually almost spot on. In my Dockerfile, I added `COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/` after I copied over the package.json, and that solved the issue

Comment: I had the same issue. I accidentally use yarn for my old project, which was using npm as package manager. Then yarn creates a new lock file. Boom, issue raised. Thank you, I appreciate your help to solve this out.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the `useLocation()` hook providing a generic type, this way you can override the `unknown` type set by default in `location.state`.

```js
import { RouteComponentProps, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

interface stateType {
   from: { pathname: string }
}

const { state } = useLocation<stateType>();

console.log(state.from)
```

It should work fine.

Comment: This seems a lot easier than using the third generic argument of `RouteComponentProps` to define the state type.  Thank you

Answer (score 30):

Previously, type checking was disabled for location state. That changed with https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674.

The type defaults to `unknown`, but you can change it using generics:

```
import { Location } from 'history';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { StaticContext } from 'react-router';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

type LocationState = {
    from: Location;
};

function LoginPage(
    props: RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, LocationState>,
): ReactElement {
    props.history.push(props.location.state.from.pathname);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I benefitted from @Oliver Joseph Ash answer but somehow I did not have access to `StaticContext` perhaps because I use `connected-react-router` and it has no exported member but I did not dive deep.

I created a mock type like so:

```js
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

type LocationState = {
  // ... type of members passed to state
};

type MockType = {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
};

type TypeWithLocationState = RouteComponentProps<MockType, MockType, LocationState>;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It works like a charm

```
const { valueX, valueY } = location.state as any;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as H from "history";
const location: H.Location = useLocation();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @Francisco Baralle's answer

When state could be undefined (e.g redirected from another spot which didn't contain the state). Could use:

```
 useLocation<stateProps | undefined>
```

And then to retrieve

```
 const stateValue = location.state?.stateValue
```

And then handle logic when it's undefined

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party but here is the process used which solved my problem.

The browser or React's typings comes with a Generic called history which contains the types for the location props and adding in the missing type eg. "**from**" allowed me to use location's state without issues but see an example below.

```
//types.ts
import { RouteProps } from 'react-router';

//useHistory props
export interface useHistoryProps {
  from: string;
}
```

Then in my main file

```
//main.tsx
import { History } from 'history';

const history: History<useHistoryProps> = useHistory();
```

Comment: Please add proper attribution to your answer. From what I can tell, this looks like you copied it from the transcription of a YouTube video without crediting the author (I edited the YouTube part out of your answer)

Comment: No, or you mean the Youtuber got it from here??, if you can show me where this was copied from and I would do the necessary.

The Youtube comment was used as a Joke.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was not clear to me that the YouTube comment was a joke. I thought you copied the contents of the answer from a video transcript when I saw that. I'm not the downvoter btw, but I won't be rolling back my edit as the YouTube comment is irrelevant with regards to the answer