# Property 'background' does not exist on type '{}' - React Router modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

As shown in the tutorial https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery (Line 39) it's saying `let background = location.state && location.state.background;`. Doing so I'm getting the error:

> Property 'background' does not exist on type '{}'. ts(2339)

Note: I'm using react-router-dom: "5.1.2", react: "16.12.0" and typescript: "~3.7.5".

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Have you installed `@types/react-router`?

Comment: Yes I did install it.

Comment: Caused by https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Typescript: add location state to react router component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752515/react-typescript-add-location-state-to-react-router-component)

Comment: Not really, have a look below, that fixed the issue. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Example is not written in typescript.
to remove  remove warning specify state type

```js
const location = useLocation<{ background?: Location<{} | null | undefined> }>();
```

Comment: how do you create project? with `yarn create react-app modal-gallery --template typescript` | `npx create-react-app modal-gallery --template typescript` ?

Comment: can you check if using this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-modal-gallery-v34br example.ts works for you without error?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you - optional chaning was not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you need 
import { Location } from 'history'; 
//than 
const location = useLocation<{background: Location}>();
```

Comment: const location = useLocation<{background: Location}>();

const background = location.state && location.state.background;