# How to properly type component props in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a route

```js
 <Route path="/server_form" exact={true} render={(props) => <ServerForm {...props} />}/>
```

And in the code I have a server which I want to pass when I click a button to my ServerForm

```js
let server = { url: "http://localhost", description: "" }
onClick = {() => {
    history.push({
        pathname: "/server_form",
        state: { ...server },
    })
}}
```

I tried typing props with RouteComponentProps from react-router, but no luck:

```js
type Server = {
    url: string;
    description: string;
}

interface ServerFormProps extends RouteComponentProps<Server> {

}

export function ServerForm(props: ServerFormProps) {
    console.log(props.location.state!.url);
}
```

On the line with console.log I get the following error:

```js
Property 'url' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
```

How can I properly type it?

P.S. My dependencies

```json
{
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
}
```

Comment: You need to supply the generic types for the location state, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857898/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe that fixes the issue for component, but how can I type my render function in Route then?

Comment: Have you had a specific problem with that? What error message, and have you researched it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so the problem is that render function doesn't support overloading all 3 generics of RouteComponentProps, as its signature is `render?: (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode;`. So there is no way I can pass it in the function normally. And without render function there are no props

Comment: When I add type explicitly to props as `RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, Server>` or don't type it at all, I get following error: `Type 'History<UnknownFacade>' is not assignable to type 'History<Server>'.` Which means that needed location generic is not overloaded

Comment: If you no longer have the problem in the question, please delete it or [edit] it to give a [mre] of the problem you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using new API:

```
let location = useLocation<Server>()
```